# Tkinter Scrollbar not scrolling

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll, scrollbar

I have some code which is creating a scrollable Tkinter canvas with buttons inside. I believe my configuration of the scrollbar and Canvas is ok, but when I run the program, the scrollbar does not scroll. I have looked at other solutions online and I believe I am fulfilling everything that should be applied.

Thank you for any and all help:)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


responsesFr = Frame(root, width=700, height=275, bg="#d40b04")
responseFrCoverCanvas = Canvas(root, width=700,height=14 ,highlightthickness=0, border=0,bg="#d40b04")
w = Canvas(responsesFr, width=650, height=225, borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0,background="white")
w.config(scrollregion=[0,0,1000,225])

for column in range(30):
    button1 = Button(w, width=20, height=4)
    button1.pack(side='left', padx=25)
    if column == 29:
        w.config(scrollregion=[0,0,1000,1000])
        print("done")
    else:
        pass
w.pack(padx=25,pady=10)
hbar=Scrollbar(responsesFr, orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(padx=25, side=TOP, fill=X)
hbar.config(command=w.xview)
w.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set)

responsesFr.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you have to include the image in it? Its hard to try to test it when we dont have the picture

Comment: Sorry, should have seen that. Ive edited it to take it out. @v0rtex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't scroll things added with `pack`. You must use the canvas `create_window` method to add widgets to the canvas.